# Static website using React

Tags: reactjs, gulp, react-router, static-site

I am making a static website and using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) to process all the files.

## Static HTML

Firstly I had a bunch of static HTML files each with the content for the page. Example `index.html`:

```html
<p>Home</p>
```

Then I had a `layout.html` file with HTML that is the same for each page. It looked like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="contents">
      <%= contents %>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/scripts.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then, in the `gulpfile`, I would process the pages using the [gulp-wrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrap) plugin like this:

```js
gulp.task("html", () => {
  return gulp.src(["html/**/*.html", "!html/layout.html"])
    .pipe(wrap({ src: project.layout }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(project.build));
});
```

And this, as expected, created all the HTML files as required.

## Using React

Now I want to use [React](https://facebook.github.io/react). So in my main script that gets included into every page I wrote this:

```js
import React      from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

render((
  <p>This would be some Page component...</p>
), document.body);
```

This, of course, replaces the body content of every page, so I turned to the [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router):

```js
import React                             from "react";
import { render }                        from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from "react-router";

render((
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

I guess this would work (after putting some routes into the router, of course), but what are the HTML files for?

## Questions

- How do I use the HTML files? Will I just leave them empty so that Gulp generates the same HTML file `layout.html` everywhere it's needed? (Or something equal to copy the file...) I need some files there so that routes like `site.me/about` work. This would leave everything up to the router.
- Do I render a page-specific component in every page HTML file? This means having something like this in the `index.html` file:

```html
<script>render(<Index />, document.body);</script>
```

- Some other `react-router` wizardry?

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done in this case is to have just one single HTML file that has the application in it. I then set this file up on the server to always be loaded irrespective of what the actual request path is.

Once that's done, reading the path on React Router and showing the correct components happens as usual. The key is that all routes load the same HTML page and the routing (deciding which component to show where and which props to load into it) happens inside React Router.

Comment: The problem is that I want to make a _static website_ to host at [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). So you suggest to just duplicate the main HTML file wherever needed?

Comment: In that case, yes. Just duplicate the file for every route.

Comment: Most commercial providers will have rewrite rules you can use: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects#redirects-and-rewrite-rules - the easiest I've found is S3 + Cloudfront, though.

Comment: After reading [the Netlify documentation](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps), I guess this would work (`_redirects` file): `/*    /index.html   200`. Thanks!